# Scoring with MOJO in pyspark/jupyter env

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, mojo

I would like to score an incoming data pipeline in Pyspark/Jupyter notebook with H2O's mojo object.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","/path/h2o-genmodel.jar") \
                    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/path/h2o-genmodel.jar") \
                    .config("spark.jars","/path/h2o-genmodel.jar")
MojoModel = spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.MojoModel
EasyPredictModelWrapper = spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper
RowData = spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.easy.Rowdata
mojo = MojoModel.load("mojo_path")
```

when I run:

```
print(spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.MojoModel)
```

I get "py4j.java_gateway.JavaPackage object at 0x7fb8ac768d30". Is this telling me that the package has been successfully loaded and seen by spark?

However, the command

```
mojo = MojoModel.load("mojo_path")
```

gives "TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable"

Please advise on other dependencies or config settings. The config settings I chose are based on several other stackoverflow tickets.